# In SQL Server can multiple tables be updated in one statement?

Tags: sql-server

Can we update a data in multiple tables with one query?

```
UPDATE table1, table2 
SET table1.column_name = values,
    table2.column_name = values 
WHERE 
    table1.column_name = values 
    AND table2.column_name = values
```

Is this query correct?

Comment: NO. You can update one and only one table at a time. There is no "work around" or exception to that.

Comment: **WHY don't you just simply check** the [official MSDN documentation on `UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) ?? That's the **authoritative** source to tell you what the T-SQL syntax is

Answer (score 3):

No you can not and you should write two separate Update statement. But in order to make sure that the both Updates are executed successfully, you can put them inside a transaction.